# Small girl visits sweet innocent-seeming Martian old lady. She is far less harmless than she seems

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, mars

I read this about ten years ago but it seemed much older.

The Martian seems like an innocent sweet old lady. A human girl visits her house and watches her baking something like apple pie.

The girl says she heard that in the olden days before humans came to Mars, Martians used to kill babies. The child tries unsuccessfully to pronounce infanticide. The sweet old lady agrees that this did used to happen. She says it was terrible but it was the only way they had of controlling their population.

The old lady asks if the girl has told her mother where she is. She says the mother must be worrying about her.  The girl says she has not. All the human adults are off searching for some missing boys. The girl is convinced the boys are not in danger, just up to mischief.

It is strongly implied that both the missing boys and this girl end up

> cooked in the old lady's earth-made oven.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is "[One Martian Afternoon](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?92888)" (1953) by Tom Leahy.  It was first published in [*If*, July 1953](https://archive.org/details/1953-07_IF/page/74/mode/2up), reprinted as a chapbook in 2009, and collected a few times since (but not earlier).  It's possible you found one of the recent reprintings.

Aunt Twylee (the Martian) has an Earth-made stove:

> The kitchen was dark and cool, and filled with the odors of the wonderful edibles the old Martian had created on and in the Earth-made stove. She opened the Earth-made refrigerator that stood in the corner and withdrew an Earth-made bottle filled with Martian apple juice.

Marilou (the child) can't pronounce "infanticide:"

> "True? How can I say, dear? I don't know what he said."
>
> "Well, I mean, that when us Earth people came, you Martians did inf... infan..."
>
> "Infanticide?" Aunt Twylee interrupted, rolling the dough on the board a little flatter, a little faster.

And Aunt Twylee asks if anyone knows where Marilou is:

> "Do your parents know where you are, child?" Aunt Twylee asked, as she took the bowl from Marilou's hands. She began dicing the apples into a dough-lined cassarole.
>
> "No, they don't," Marilou replied. She sprayed the air with little particles of apple as she talked. "Everybody's gone to the hills to look for the boys."

The ending is a bit different than you recall; Aunt Twylee is making a simple apple cobbler, not cooking the children (at least not yet).  But under the cover of a thunderstorm she cuts Marilou's throat and lays her out with the other missing children.

The story is also available as HTML or plaintext at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29975).

Comment: Many thanks. I also found a copy on Project Gutenberg. Personally I find PG text files easier to read than scans of paper materials. Would you like to add this to your answer? https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29975

Comment: @JudithJones Done.